# Probability proof - Independent events

Tags: probability

Prove if a and b are independent events, that a' and b' are independent.

I think you have to use that p(a and b) = p(b)p(a) but that is not enough.

Anyone know how to help me? I have been thinking about it for some time now :p

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $p(a\mbox{ or }b)=p(a)+p(b)-p(a)p(b)$ since $a$ and $b$ are independent.
$$p(a'\mbox{ and }b')=1-p(a\mbox{ or }b)=1-(p(a)+p(b)-p(a)p(b))=1-p(a)-p(b)+p(a)p(b)=(1-p(a))(1-p(b))=p(a')p(b')$$
hence $a'$ and $b'$ are independent.